# Android: Fatal Exception when I rotate a FragmentActivity (simple example)

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation-changes

My code works fine if my app extends Activity, but if I change to FragmentActivity (only that) logcat return a Fatal Exception...

I appreciate any help, I create a simple example (which also breaks):

```
package com.example.changeorientation;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            onCreate(new Bundle());
        }

    }
```

and the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.changeorientation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.changeorientation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and finally the logcat:

```
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachActivity(FragmentManager.java:1867)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:198)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.example.changeorientation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.example.changeorientation.MainActivity.onConfigurationChanged(MainActivity.java:22)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:3924)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:4017)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2106)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-28 22:52:28.824: E/AndroidRuntime(2675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are calling "onCreate(new Bundle());" in your onConfigurationChanged method which is actually causing the problem.

When you rotate your device android does restart your activity itself and it will call onCreate by itself but now since you have declared that you are going to take care of orientationchange by yourself by doing this:

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

onCreate will not be called since it has already been called. And you should not call onCreate by yourself since it's the systems task to call it. And that is why you are getting the error.

My Suggestion would be to do something like this:

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // load new UI and other stuff for landscape mode do setContentView(for landscape) if you need
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        // load new UI and other stuff for portrait mode do setContentView(for portrait) if you need    
    }
}
```

Comment: but I add android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"> to avoid that... If I remove onCreate then the device dont change his layout by a landscape version (dont call onCreate by itself)

Comment: I check that in my project and dont change the portrait version for the landscape version

Comment: @naxo Edited my answer after reading your comments. i did use this method awhile ago, check if it helps you. Thanks :)

Comment: In this way I'll have to repeat all Oncreate's code inside if and inside else if ... One solution I've found is to create a new funcion thats repeats all code inside onCreate, except `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` obviously, and call this new funcion in onConfigurationChanged but... Its an ugly solution

Comment: Though you can reuse code for both landscape and portrait mode when do this way but that's the way to go since you are not letting android to handle orientation change.